what is the correct way to install the [latest] NVIDIA driver in Linux
NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-555.42.02.run
obtained from cuda_12.5.0_555.42.02_linux.run --extract=<folder>
Running Linux (RHEL-8.10 to be specific) what is the best way to install the nvidia graphics driver?
I ask because nvidia has 3 different download methods when getting from developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads...

rpm (local)
rpm (network)
runfile (local)

And then if you go to nvidia.com/download specifically for the nvidia driver I see version 440.95.01 where the cuda 12.5.0 gives 555.42.02.  And if you go this route you are getting a .run file that can be used without an internet connection.
I remember seeing a youtube of Linus (however many years ago) giving the finger on camera, directed at "nvidia", while on the topic of graphics or whatever they were talking about.
And with problems I've had with RHEL-7 and nvidia drivers in servers, a RHEL support ticket response was we do not support 3rd party software/drivers.  But they did give me instructions to rpm -ev --nodeps mesa* xorg-x11-drv-nouveau followed by reinstalling and a dracut -vf.  And that seemed to fix lost console graphics at the time when nvidia was installed to support other software that needed it.
How do you install the NVIDIA graphics driver in Linux?  Is there a best way?  Is there a way to not do it and for what reason?  I've tried doing it with dkms installed and have had limited success, but have also run into headaches still.  It seems the only reliable way is to always be prepared after a yum update with new kernel to formally uninstall the nvidia driver, reboot, and then cleanly install nvidia, all with modprobe blacklisting nouveau.  I'm hoping there's a better way now?  I still do not have console graphics on servers when nvidia is installed, and once it does get lost I often can't fix it unless I completely reinstall linux from iso.  This is also with dell servers having a mainboard vga output for console graphics (matrox chip?) and a nvidia GPGPU (datacenter) type graphics card (p100 or v100) that does not have any output ports.

I would recommend editing the question to not ask about a "best" way, but focus more on explaining the problems you experienced with the three methods you indicated, and asking on how to solve these particular issues. As you can see, the "best" aspect already incurrec close-votes as "opinion-based" ...

The installation method documented by Red Hat for RHEL 8 and 9, and documented by NVIDIA, is to use the nvidia-driver module. On RHEL 8, tracking the latest drivers:
# subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms
# subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms
# dnf module install nvidia-driver:latest

The drivers are pre-compiled and don’t rely on dkms; the module also ensures that kernels are only installed if they have corresponding drivers:

When using precompiled drivers, a plugin for the dnf package manager is enabled that cleans up stale .ko files. To prevent system breakages, the NVIDIA dnf plugin also prevents upgrading to a kernel for which no precompiled driver yet exists. This can delay the application of security fixes but ensures that a tested kernel and driver combination is always used.

